# How to have Craft 3 and 2 on same host?

Tags: craft3, craft2, configuration

I have a Craft 2 installation that I'm upgrading to Craft 3.

I've got v3 running locally in its own virtual host, but now I need to **temporarily** put the dev v3 instance in the same hosting account as the live v2, with the v3 instance resolving at a dev subdomain:

```
account root
    craft              <-- v2 system
    craft              <-- v3 executable
    config … templates <-- other v3 dependencies
    public_html        <-- live web root
    dev                <-- dev web root
```

Given the naming conflict between the v2 system folder and the v3 executable, can I exclude the v3 executable and have v3 still run?

Or can I put all the v3 stuff in its own folder **still above web root** and then tell the dev index.php where to find it? It's not clear to me from [the doc on customising directory structure](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/directory-structure.html) that I can do that.

I know there is a doc on [moving Craft files](https://craftcms.com/guides/moving-craft-files) but that focuses on moving *into* web root (in my case, dev web root), which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Both the `craft/` folder name in Craft 2, and the `craft` executable in Craft 3, can be renamed.

Since the `craft` executable is user-facing (when SSH’d in), I’d recommend leaving that alone and rename your `craft/` folder to something else, maybe `craft2/`. Then in `public_html/index.php`, update your `$craftPath` variable to point to the new location:

```php
$craftPath = '../craft2';
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon. Obvious now you explain it [self facepalm].

Comment: Noting here for others that in Craft 2's `index.php`, `CRAFT_BASE_PATH` is defined as `$craftPath`. At least, it was in mine.

Comment: @JonathanSchofield Doh, thanks! Just updated my answer.